# Как сделать выбор ОС при загрузке

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dual-boot

На ноуте стоят 2 ОС. Ubuntu 13.04 и Windows 7. Через GParted разбил жесткий диск и под убунту поставил Windows 7. При загрузке по умолчанию загружается Windows 7. А так же можно ли как то сделать, чтобы при перезагрузке убунту грузилась убунту, а при перезагрузке виндовса соотвественно windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последующей установкой Винды вы убили загрузчик Убунты - да, так нахально ведут себя все системы от Майкрософт.
При желании иметь Линукс + Виндоуз на компе, сначала ставят Виндоуз, а потом Линукс. В этом случае Линух сам все разрулит и корректно пропишет.
Но и в вашем случае не все потеряно: 1) необходимо найти LiveCD с Вашей версией Убунты; 2) почитать о восстановлении загрузчика grub в инете; 3) воспользоваться рекомендациями по восстановлению, загрузившись с Лайва.

Comment: Если Windows деинсталлировать, то граб будет стандартным загрузчиком?

Comment: А зачем ее деинсталлировать? - ведь есть же причина по которой вы Винду ставили. Есть. Вот и задайтесь целью восстановить grub. Тем более, что удалив Винду, автоматически не восстановите grub :) .  Или, если у Вас сейчас в обоих операционках ничего серьезного нет, то можно форматнуть разделы (полностью очистить комп), а потом ставить в указанном мной порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Я могу предложить только один удобный вариант (уверен, что он не единственный)вариант заключается в установке системы и [загрузчика](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) в [BOOT SECTOR](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) своего диска, а не в [MBR](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBR).т.е. дефолтный вариант для убунты:

```
|[MBR] GRUB\ | UBUNTU /dev/sda1 | [BR] WIN /dev/sda2
```

должен быть изменён на:

```
|[MBR]\- [BR] GRUB UBUNTU /dev/sda1 |-[BR] WIN /dev/sda2
```

в этом случае будет грузиться та система, раздел которой помечен, как BOOT. Т.е. при перезагрузке одна и та же, а если понадобиться перегрузиться в другую, нужно будет изменить [активный раздел](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%20hdd) и ребутнуться.Надеюсь всё понятно объяснил )

Comment: ничего не понял)) но все равно спасибо за отклик)

Comment: если совсем ничего, то мне будет тяжело объяснить. Может что-то всё-таки понятно? от этого и будет плясать

Comment: Что вы имели ввиду под словом система (ОС?) и где находится бут сектор диска? Что такое активный раздел?

Comment: система - ОСбут сектор (дана ссылка на вики) - это место в каждом разделе диска, где может быть его  (этого раздела) собственный загрузчикактивный раздел (тоже дана ссылка, почитайте, там не много) - это раздел, который специальным образом помечен в MBR, которому передаётся управление загрузкой при отсутствии этого самого загрузчика в этом самом MBR. В линуксе можно посмотреть командой (активный раздел помечен звёздочкой)    fdisk -lдля управления можно также использовать fdisk, cfdisk, gparted или всё, что вам удобно.